# Write HashMap to Csv File

Tags: java, csv, hashmap, supercsv

I have a hashmap with a String key and List(String) as values.

**For Example:**

```
Key | Values
John | GroupName1,GroupName2,GroupName3
Nick | Groupname4,GroupName1
```

I would like to write this hashmap to a csv file such that my csv file contains rows as below:

```
John,GroupName1,GroupName2,GroupName3    
Nick,Groupname4,GroupName1
```

I tried:

```
Map<String, List<String>> usersmap = (Map<String, List<String>>) model.get("users"); //this is my map
StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
ICsvListWriter listWriter;
listWriter = new CsvListWriter(output, CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : usersmap.entrySet()) {
    listWriter.write(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

but it doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Can you specify "doesn't seem right" ?

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: Yes of Course.I mean that listWriter.write  can take a String -->key 
and a List<String> --> entry.getValue() as arguments? or i need to pass two strings? My problem is the List<String>

Comment: The thing is that you are breaking the CSV concept. Keys should be the header of your file and the Values should be the line under the keys. Why don't you just use a OutputStreamWriter to make what you want ?

Comment: In the Documentation of CsvListWriter Class i found
this :   write(String... columns) -->Writes an array of strings as columns of a CSV file. 
So, if i create a new list inside the loop  and "merge" the key and values as a new List<String> , it will work?

Comment: My problem is that when a user downloads the csv-file and opens it in excel i want the following format:
first row{

  first column: John(its the key)

  second column: GroupName1 

  third column: GroupName2 

etc...}
second row{
    first column:Nick(its the key)
    second column: GroupName
    third column: otherGroupName
   etc...}

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your List into a comma separated string using `String.join(...)`

```
listWriter.write(entry.getKey(), String.join(",", entry.getValue());
```

Java documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-